# ¿Es posible añadir un botón adicional en un fontdialog en c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy intentado mejorar un fontdialog, para lo cual necesito agregar un botón de extra para que nos dé paso a otro formulario. ¿Se puede añadir un botón extra a un fontdialog? ¿Se puede realizar esta tarea? Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Crea un un UserControl nuevo. Clic derecho arriba del proyecto/Add/UserControl y disennalo a tu gusto

Comment: Gracias. Ya estoy en ello. Un saludo